# Subdomain-subdomain wildcard

Tags: security, ssl, subdomain

So, I'm wondering if it's possible to buy a wildcard-ssl-certificate for a subdomain.
So for example, I have the subdomain test.domain.com propagated to my server.

I want sub1.test.domain.com and sub2.test.domain.com to both be secured via the same wildcard cert. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  It is possible.  The extra component in the domain name doesn't matter.